# using array formula to average if

Tags: excel, array-formulas

i have some cells `d1:d10`. Some have numbers, others contain `""`. The `""` is the result of an `=iferror(,"")` function to leave a blank cell.

I am trying to average `d1:d10` but only including the cells that are not `""`.

I have `=AVERAGE(IF(D12:D51<>"",D12:D51))` followed by ctrl+shft+enter but it is still taking the average of all the cells (essentially taking the sum and dividing by 10, where I want it to take the sum and divide by less than 10 depending on the number of `""` cells)

Comment: I've tried it by filling in a range with numbers and a few cells `=""`. A simple  `Avg(A1:A10)` ignores the cells with `=""`. Not sure a CSE is needed here at all. Perhaps... your `iferror()` is returning a `0` and you have 0 values supressed on your workbook's options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your problem in Excel 2013.
Normally, Excel's average function ignores text, empty cells and logical values. So, the following formula should do what you are trying to do.

```
=AVERAGE(D1:D10)
```

The if clause in your function returns either some numbers or FALSE. Again, normally, Excel's average function ignores FALSE values so it shouldn't behave like you said. If it somehow is converting boolean values to numeric values based on Excel's version (FALSE to zero) you can just give a string instead of a boolean value so it has to ignore those values:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(D1:D10<>"", D1:D10, "s"))
```

Alternatively you can calculate the average without the average function:

```
=SUM(IF(D1:D10<>"", D1:D10))/COUNT(IF(D1:D10<>"", D1:D10))
```